# RCP view hang issue for linux

Tags: eclipse, swt, rcp

In my eclipse RCP application, A view which we are launching to show data hangs in Linux environment but able to show view data in the windows environment. What can be the reason? Thanks in advance.  Its keep on hung state at below trace and freeze the view.

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._pango_layout_get_pixel_size(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.pango_layout_get_pixel_size(OS.java:16239)
        at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.computeStringSize(GC.java:3000)
        at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.textExtent(GC.java:4148)
        at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.stringExtent(GC.java:4085)
        at org.eclipse.swt.custom.TableCursor.paint(TableCursor.java:335)
        at org.eclipse.swt.custom.TableCursor$1.handleEvent(TableCursor.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4454)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1388)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1412)
```

Comment: Impossible to say without you showing us your code and where the issue is occurring. [edit] your question and add the code.

Comment: Sounds like you're using some sort of system native libraries. But as @greg-449 pointed out, we cant do much without your source code.

Comment: @JakobSachs This could easily just be doing something wrong in SWT code - sometimes bad code does work on one platform but fails on the others.